# Installing CakePHP 2.4.7 on Windows

Tags: cakephp

I am facing issue in my first intallation of CakePHP.

I am working on Windows OS and using WAMP. I am able to point my browser to localhost -> phpcake to open my installation of CakePHP.

However I get an error as below:

```
Missing Controller

Error: PhpcakeController could not be found.
```

Following are the steps which I followed for installing CakePHP:

1. Unzipped CakePHP, version 2.4.7 and loaded that in my WAMP
2. Created database using phpMyAdmin
3. Updated the app\Config\database.php file with login, password and databasename

The contents of the .htaccess files of cake is as below:

phpcake/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

phpcake/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

phpcake/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase D:/Vivek/phpcake/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The mod_rewrite is disabled on my Apache. If I enable it, then I get 404 error on launching CakePHP install.

Could you guide me as to which step am I missing?

Comment: Have you check the .htaccess configs of cake? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: @Nunser I checked the .htaccess files and the documentation. i modified the question to include the contents of .htaccess files.

Comment: You have to use mod_rewrite (even if it gives you a 404 error, we can try to debug that). If you don't want to use mod_rewrite, you need to [read this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl). The `.htaccess` file in webroot folder, didn't it work just out of the box? Normally I don't have to do anything to any .htaccess after installing cakephp. Try returning that .htaccess to default and enabling mod_rewrite. Just to make sure, have you [set the permissions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#permissions) correctly?

Comment: @Nunser thank you for pointing me in right directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working. This is what i was doing (wrong).

In my WAMP i created an alias directory. Apache -> Alias -> Add an Alias Directory. In this alias i pointed to the location of my CakePHP unzipped folder. I updated the App/Config/Database.php to point to created MySQL database. However on selecting mod_rewrite module in Apache i was getting 404/403 errors. And without mod_rewrite i was getting missing controller error.

```
Missing Controller

Error: PhpcakeController could not be found.
```

I tried fresh installations 3 times with same results.

My understanding is that the **mod_rewrite**, the instructions in **Alias** file and **.htaccess** files were creating this trouble.

So this is what i did (Worked):

I copied my CakePHP into WAMP's **www** directory. That's it, it did the trick. I went through various articles about .htaccess,  and mod_rewrite. Frankly speaking it is complex for me.

Comment: Great you got it working :) Remember to accept your answer when you have a chance.